# Why Is RequireJs Passing in Null?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, amd

I have two JS files:

#### Case.js

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports){
    var Case;
    (function (Case) {
        ...
    })(Case = exports.Case || (exports.Case = {}));
});
```

#### Ribbon.js

```
define(["require", "exports", "case"], function(require, exports, case){
    var Ribbon;
    (function (Ribbon) {
        function foo() {
            case.something();
        }
        Ribbon.foo = foo;
    })(Ribbon= exports.Ribbon|| (exports.Ribbon = {}));
});
```

I'm calling them in this manner:

```
require(["case"], function (case) {
    ...
});

// Sometime later as a result of a user click event
require(["ribbon"], function (ribbon){
    // *** ISSUE **** ribbon is undefined
    ribbon.foo();
});
```

But when I do, then the ribbon object is always undefined.  From what I can tell, the only reason it would be null, is if there is a circular dependency, but I don't see one.  Ribbon depends on Case, Case does not depend on ribbon.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `case` undefined as well when you attempt to require it?

Comment: @acdcjunior no, it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved... a co-worker of mine deployed a non-AMD version of Ribbon.js, which is why I wasn't getting my Ribbon object returned.